# python regex matching file names

Tags: python, regex

I have the below file names and would like to group them:

Group1:

```
C7_S6_L001.sorted.bam
C7_S6_L002.sorted.bam
C7_S6_L003.sorted.bam
C7_S6_L004.sorted.bam
```

Group2:

```
CL3_S8_L001.sorted.bam
CL3_S8_L002.sorted.bam
CL3_S8_L003.sorted.bam
CL3_S8_L004.sorted.bam
```

Group3:

```
CL5-B1_S4_L001.sorted.bam
CL5-B1_S4_L002.sorted.bam
CL5-B1_S4_L003.sorted.bam
CL5-B1_S4_L004.sorted.bam
```

How would the regular expression looks for it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the grouping key is everything before the `_L` and digits at the beginning of file names, you can use the following regular expression to capture the group keys using *saving groups*:

```
([A-Z0-9-_]+)_L\d{3}\.sorted\.bam
```

Working example using [`defaultdict` collection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint
import re

filenames = [
    "C7_S6_L001.sorted.bam",
    "C7_S6_L002.sorted.bam",
    "C7_S6_L003.sorted.bam",
    "C7_S6_L004.sorted.bam",

    "CL3_S8_L001.sorted.bam",
    "CL3_S8_L002.sorted.bam",
    "CL3_S8_L003.sorted.bam",
    "CL3_S8_L004.sorted.bam",

    "CL5-B1_S4_L001.sorted.bam",
    "CL5-B1_S4_L002.sorted.bam",
    "CL5-B1_S4_L003.sorted.bam",
    "CL5-B1_S4_L004.sorted.bam"
]

pattern = re.compile(r"([A-Z0-9-_]+)_L\d{3}\.sorted\.bam")
grouped = defaultdict(list)

for filename in filenames:
    match = pattern.search(filename)
    if match:
        key = match.group(1)
        grouped[key].append(filename)

pprint(grouped)
```

Prints:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'C7_S6': ['C7_S6_L001.sorted.bam',
                       'C7_S6_L002.sorted.bam',
                       'C7_S6_L003.sorted.bam',
                       'C7_S6_L004.sorted.bam'],
             'CL3_S8': ['CL3_S8_L001.sorted.bam',
                        'CL3_S8_L002.sorted.bam',
                        'CL3_S8_L003.sorted.bam',
                        'CL3_S8_L004.sorted.bam'],
             'CL5-B1_S4': ['CL5-B1_S4_L001.sorted.bam',
                           'CL5-B1_S4_L002.sorted.bam',
                           'CL5-B1_S4_L003.sorted.bam',
                           'CL5-B1_S4_L004.sorted.bam']})
```